# Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'. / Flutter can't assign constructor in class

Tags: dart

```
void main() {
 Login('John');
}

class User {
 String name;
 User(this.name);
}

class Login {
 User user;
 Login(this.user);

 print(user.name);
}
```

Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'.

How to fix this error or use other use case;

Comment: Can you show an example code?

Comment: Added an answer with details.

Comment: Your Login class contain User class and you are tryeing the Login('String') this is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Login` constructor takes a `User` as first argument, not a `String`. You need to construct a `User` object and provide that to your `Login` constructor.

```
void main() {
  Login(User('John'));
}
```

Another issue in your code is the `print(user.name);` line directly in your `Login` class definition. That is not allowed. If you want to execute code as part of calling the constructor, you can do that like:

```
  Login(this.user) {
    print(user.name);
  }
```

So the full solution is going to look like this:

```
void main() {
  Login(User('John'));
}

class User {
  String name;
  User(this.name);
}

class Login {
  User user;
  Login(this.user) {
    print(user.name);
  }
}
```